# node js schema format to store and fetch mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have no more idea about schema design, I have created a schema in this format.

```
   var LevelSchema = new Schema(
      {

            _id: { type: String },
            name: { type: Number },
            age: { type: Number },
            level: { type: Number }              

     });
```

2). But my requirement is to create a schema in this format can it possible. I have used an array in the schema.

```
     var LevelSchema = new Schema(
       [
        {
            _id: { type: String },
            name: { type: Number },
            age: { type: Number },
            level: { type: Number }              
         }
     ]);
```

Comment: Should this also have the `mongoose` tag?

Comment: Why are you making complex `schema` while `array type` issue you can solve by programmatically

Comment: I am new in node js I have assigned a task that schema can be created in this format or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to have an array of the strucuture you have givenin this levelSchema.

```
   var LevelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
           levels: [
            {
                _id: { type: String },
                name: { type: Number },
                age: { type: Number },
                level: { type: Number }              
            }      ]
         });
```

If your intention is to have multiple of records of this particular object then array of objects of this type would suffice.